# VS 2008 - ctrl-tab behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

As you may know, in `VS 2008` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> brings up a nifty navigator window with a thumbnail of each file. I love it, but there is one tiny thing that is annoying to me about this feature: *the window stays around after releasing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key*. When doing an <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> in windows, you can hit tab to get to the item you want (while still holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key), and then when you find what you want, *lifting up* on the <kbd>alt</kbd> key selects that item.

I wish `VS 2008` would do the same. For me, when I lift off of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, the window is still there. I have to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to actually select the item. I find this annoying.

Does anyone know how to make `VS 2008` dismiss the window on the *release* of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably have the text-to-speech narrator enabled.

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2467648&SiteID=1&mode=1

> Just uncheck all checkboxes under
>   "Text-To-Speech" narrator software.
>
> --> To open Narrator using the keyboard, press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>**, press **<kbd>R</kbd>**,
>   type narrator, and then press Enter.

This one drove me crazy for several months until I found this posting.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but I tried it and it didn't work. I started Narrator as described and unchecked all checkboxes. I also unchecked "Use Narrator" in the Control Panel. I still have to press Enter after Ctrl+Tab. What else could I try?

Comment: I got the same problem in Win7 now

Comment: The link appears to be broken now, but the solution still works.

Comment: I've also noticed this behaviour when running the Windows 7 Magnifier - which I'm sure I'm not running intentionally, but hitting Win-+ brings it up, then closing it explicitly makes the Ctrl-Tab behaviour return to normal...

Comment: Bottom line is that VS ties into the Windows accessibility APIs. I got this unhelpful behavior in Visual Studio 2012 after I played with speech recognition on Windows 8. **I had to explicitly close speech recognition while VS was open.** Same probably goes for other accessibility tools.

Answer (score 5):

I found this behaviour when I was running VS2008 under windows 7 and had been using the magnifier app.

I suspect it would similarly occur under vista.

Basically I had zoomed all the way back out but not shut down the magnifier app. Once it was shut down, things returned to normal.

Answer (score 3):

This bloody thing is haunting me as well. Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and Windows 7 64-bit. Setting the registry key mentioned in this thread won't help. Sara Ford brags that she knows the right key (http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/01/04/did-you-know-use-ctrl-tab-to-bring-up-the-ide-navigator-to-get-a-bird-s-eye-view-and-navigation-of-all-open-files-and-tool-windows-in-visual-studio.aspx) but she won't tell. I guess the marvelous tip is too large to fit on the margin of the page or something.

Also turning all the narrator options off or on doesn't help (but it does make me and my co-workers crazy.) As a bonus starting the narrator.exe (WIN-R narrator ENTER) starts up the windows magnifier (magnifier.exe) and it immediately zooms into molecule level without giving way to zoom back (ctrl +/-, win -/+, win-mouse wheel, esc doesn't work.) Have to kill it from task manager, which is bloody easy when each pixel is the size of a pick-up truck. Magnifier never starts up when you need it (supposed to start up with win-+), but it does occasionally go into mode where it starts up ON EACH BLOODY LOGIN, remote desktop or not. And zooms into atom scale with no way to get back. The later (week or so) it goes away. The control panel setting doesn't seem to help.

Also, I've had this sticky ctrl-tab issue at least twice to three times (right now I'm having it) and it has gone away after few weeks without clear reason why. I've just bit my teeth and gone on. But now I've had enough.

Microsoft: I won't blame you on adding accessability features for disabled people, but for god's sake don't in-your-face them at me all the fscking time. Fix the bloody thing, all I'll make sure you're seriously need accessability features the rest of your life.

Comment: I now just live with the problem, enjoyed your rant though.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this issue reassigning the ctrl-tab shortcut key to `Window.NextDocumentWindow` instead of `Window.NextDocumentWindowNav` (*IDE Navigator*). None of the above workarounds fixed the problem for VS 2010 on Win 7.

MS needs to fix this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Strange.  My VS2008SP1 install exhibits your desired behavior (in a web application project).  I do not recall making any explicit changes.

Answer (score 1):

When "Windows Speech Recognition" is running (even though not listening to commands), the VS2010 exhibits this behavior. Exiting "Windows Speech Recognition" restores the default i.e. the selection can be changed by pressing Tab key again and again while keeping the Ctrl key pressed and document is selected as soon as Ctrl key is released.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still needed a fix for this (I've encountered this behavior in VS2010) what you can do is:

- Close VS
- Enable sticky keys
- Reopen VS
- Disable sticky keys

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "narrator" answer.  I'm pretty sure it's to allow time for the narrator to read the choices...  you can then "enter" the selection when you're sure of your choice.

Otherwise, check your 'sticky keys' settings (control panel\accessibility options\keyboard) and uncheck the options.

Answer (score 0):

Just turning off the narrator didn't work for me.

What I did (besides unchecking the narrator stuff) was go to the Control panel's *Ease of Access Center* on each of the *Explore All Settings* screens, unchecked any options which were still checked, and then clicked <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Once I did this, things went back to working.

Even if none of the checkboxes are checked on one of the explore all settings screen make sure to still click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button, as it seems that just unchecking the narrator stuff does not always work - but clicking on the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button on the various sections will effectively reset and apply the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue with VS2012 today; It was all good -- releasing Ctrl key will activate the doc that had focus on that nifty pop up window.

My cause was 'Inspect' that I started using this morning. Apparently it holds the pop up window in order to give you more time to play around.

Simply kill 'Inspect', all back normal.
I don't know the fix to have 'Inspect' running & normal behaviour at the same time.